# Syntax error? Ruby bug? Issue with instance variable incrementing with += 1?

Tags: ruby

```
def isPrime?(num)

    i = 2

    @isFalse = 0

    while i < num
        divisible = ((num % i) == 0)
        if divisible
            @isFalse += 1
            return false
        end
        i += 1
    end
    true
end

def primes(max)
    startTime = Time.now
        (2..max).each do |p|
            puts "#{p} #{isPrime?(p)}"
        end
    endTime = Time.now

    puts "--------------------------------------------------"
    puts "   FALSE values in range from (2 thru #{max}): #{@isFalse}  \n    TRUE values in range from (2 thru #{max}): #{max-1-@isFalse}"
    puts "\nTotal time to calculate is #{endTime - startTime} seconds!"
end

primes(10)
```

`isPrime?` checks if a given number is a prime number.
`primes` loads a range of numbers and checks if each is a prime.

I want to know how many numbers are prime within the range and how many aren't.

I added `@isFalse += 1` thinking I can increment each time false is returned so that I can determine how many numbers in the range are false and use this to subtract from `max` to get how many numbers are true.

Entire code is working correctly except `@isFalse` is not properly incrementing. Why is that? Thanks for the help.

**--UPDATE--**
My Output: added `puts "About to increment @isFalse"` before  `@isFalse += 1`

```
2 true
3 true
About to increment @isFalse
4 false
5 true
About to increment @isFalse
6 false
7 true
About to increment @isFalse
8 false
About to increment @isFalse
9 false
About to increment @isFalse
10 false
--------------------------------------------------
   FALSE values in range from (2 thru 10): 1  
    TRUE values in range from (2 thru 10): 8
```

Comment: Quick debugging check: print something before the `@isFalse += 1` line (eg, `puts "About to increment @isFalse"`). This should help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Following your suggestion does in fact output the string 5 times `puts "About to increment @isFalse"`

Comment: @alecbenzer any other suggestion? I am stumped here.

Comment: Each time `isPrime?` is called, `@isFalse` is reset to `0`. So the result of `@isFalse` being 1 is from the last time `isPrime?` was called (with `num` equal to 10, incrementing `@isFalse` to 1).

Comment: Please, read [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and keep writing with this style guide.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier, Thanks for the link. Looks very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@isFalse = 0` is inside your `isPrime?` method. Get it out of there!

Comment: How do you suggest I initialize it? If it's not there I get an undefined error. Please explain.

Comment: Literally outside the method (and while you'r at it , consider renaming it to `non_prime_count` or somesuch).

Comment: Great. I see my mistake now. By the way the naming is because I had a `@isFalse` and `@isTrue` - I decided that was kind of redundant so I modified for just `@isFalse`. Long story short I was intending to change the name to something clearer as you suggested. I'm seeing my error. Having `@isFalse` in the method was a problem even though not in the `while` because the `prime` method was calling it with each successive number. Which is why I would only get one false which applied to the last method call of `prime`. Thank you, Your one liner was exactly what the doctor ordered! :) Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Each time `isPrime?` is called, `@isFalse` is reset to 0. So the result of `@isFalse` being 1 is from the last time `isPrime?` was called (with `num` equal to 10, incrementing `@isFalse` to 1).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to find out the number of primes in that range using `@isFalse`. If that is the case, you should instead use the following modification of your code (although, I do not recommend checking for primes in this way, and the code is really inefficient):

Basically, I removed the instance variable `@isFalse` altogether, and checked whether a number is prime or not in your second method, instead. The code is much cleaner that way, and really does what you intend it to do.

The problem with your code is that `@isFalse` is being reset to `0` everytime your first method `isPrime?` was being called, and hence, does not properly reflect the number of primes in the given range.

```
def isPrime?(num)
    i = 2
    while i < num
        divisible = ((num % i) == 0)
        return false if divisible
        i += 1
    end
    true
end

def primes(max)
    startTime = Time.now
        is_prime = 0
        (2..max).each do |p|
            if isPrime?(p)
                is_prime += 1
                puts p
        end
    endTime = Time.now

    puts "--------------------------------------------------"
    puts "   FALSE values in range from (2 thru #{max}): #{is_prime}  \n    TRUE values in range from (2 thru #{max}): #{max-1-is_prime}"
    puts "\nTotal time to calculate is #{endTime - startTime} seconds!"
end

primes(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

As your question has been answered, I would like to suggest a more Ruby-like solution:

You want the method `is_prime?` to do nothing other than determine if `num` is prime:

```
def is_prime?(num)
  (2...num).each {|i| return false if num % i == 0}
  true
end
```

Do your counting of primes in the method `nbr_primes`.

```
def nbr_primes(max)
  return false if max < 2
  (2..max).reduce(0) {|tot, i| tot + (is_prime?(i) ? 1 : 0)}
end

p nbr_primes(20) # => 8
```

A few points:

- I removed the references to time and the output formatting as they are not central to the question.
- It's a Ruby convention to name methods with lower case letters and underscores.
- `(2...num)`, because it has three dots, is the sequence from 2 to (and including) `num - 1`.  We could instead write `(2..num-1)` (two dots), which is favored by some.
- `(2..max).reduce(0) {|tot, i|...}` iterates over `i` from 2 to and including `max`.  `tot`, which is `reduce`'s accumulator, is incremented by 1 for each number between 2 and `max` that is found to be prime.  The expression returns the value of `tot`, which in turn is returned by the method `nbr_primes`.  `inject` is a synonym for `reduce`.
- In checking whether a number `n` is prime, you only have to check if its divisible by numbers up to `Math.sqrt(n).to_i`.
- With `require 'prime'`, you don't have to reinvent the wheel.  For example, `Prime.prime?(7) #=> true`, and `Prime.take_while {|p| p <= 10}.size #=> [2, 3, 5, 7].size + 1 # => 4`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I find this information very helpful. I appreciate your knowledge. Thank you.